# Event triggered by a cell change

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have a validation box that has stored in it a number of sales channels i.e "SME100", "Indirect" etc...

Now I have an auto filtering system set up but I want to create an event that states, "when cell "B2" changes then activate 'Auto_Filter'".

Here is what I currently have. It doesn't return an error message but when I test it on the front end it doesn't run the macro either.

```
Private Sub CellChangeFilter()

Dim Tariff_Selection As String
    Set Tariff_Selection = Cell("B1")

If Tariff_Selection = "" Then Auto_Filter

End Sub
```

As you can see I have created a variable for the specific cell that I want the event to monitor.

Comment: Have you Googled "Worksheet_Change?

Comment: [This post has all that you need on `Worksheet_Change`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640)

Comment: I have yes but am struggling to make it work and cant understand why.All i need it to say is: If ("A1") changes then then activate "Auto_Filter" :@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, Worksheet_Change is what you want. Try this:-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If (Target.Address = Range("B2").Address) Then

     Debug.Print "Cell B2 was edited in some way"

     Auto_Filter

   End If

End Sub
```